# How to achieve manual "dapr init " instead of command "dapr init "

Tags: dapr

in my company,because of network reason,often disconnect github.com,  command of "dapr init" always failed,so I want to manual implement "dapr init " to instead of command "dapr init ", someone know detail of "dapr init" ? thx

Comment: did you try breaking down from https://github.com/dapr/cli/blob/8a5966d7bc5d4fcf1699517e83eb94934ef1dd13/pkg/standalone/standalone.go#L100 ?

Answer (score 0):

Dapr is an Open Source Project, so you can take a look at the init cmd implementation [here](https://github.com/dapr/cli/blob/master/cmd/init.go)!